# Geometry library in google-maps-api-loader vue.js

Tags: vue.js

I'm currently using the google-maps-api-loader so I can render a google map in vue.js and place markers on it. The data are all retrieved from a json file and I had no problem with the markers but now I have to connect them using an *encoded* path from the json file. I have some sample pure javascript that decodes the route and I'm trying to do the same in Vue.js but it seems the geometry thing isn't working. What can i do?

I

```
        path: google.maps.geometry.encoding.decodePath(route)
```

Answer (score 1):

First, you have to enable geometry on

```
Vue.use(VueGoogleMaps, {  load: {    key: 'xxxxxxxx',    libraries: 'places,geometry',  ,  installComponents: true});
```

Then on your target file,
initial a google:gmapApi on computed,
Finally, the path should be like this

```
:path="google && new google.maps.geometry.encoding.decodePath(routes)"
```